# Convert Json payload to dynamic object then assert dynamic object matches specific object?

Tags: c#, json

Lets say for example I have a class named **MyPayload**. I call an API that gives me some JSON, and I deserialize it as such

```
MyPayload payload = null;
String myJson = await callSomeAPI();
payload = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyPayload>(myJson);
```

This current method is great, it asserts that the json from the string myJson actually matches my DataContract. How can I instead deserialize the object so it goes into a type dynamic, and then check that the dynamic object follows the [DataContract] that is defined in MyPayload?

```
 String myJson = await callSomeAPI();
 dynamic payload = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myJson);
 MyPayload myPayload = (MyPayload)payload; //how do I check to see dynamic matches contract in MyPayload?
```

Comment: You say that the current method works, so what is the need for the other method?

Comment: You can't check this with your class, but you can if you create a JSON schema. Have a look at [Validating JSON with a JSON schema](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonSchema.htm) Regardless, you can't cast the `dynamic` to your class.

Comment: @John This current method works but I was hoping to expand this so I can hold multiple different payloads and call it as a generic function and then later on assert the payload is correct.

Comment: Its better to use Generics then dynamic object. Dyanmic type can not be compared against the actual type.

Comment: Would it be possible to instead deserialize the json into a generic type and then assert the generic type matches the contract defined in MyPayload?